# WEP > WPA? Why?

Tags: wpa2, wep

What are some reasons (if any) one would choose WEP over WPA? Clearly, WPA offers more security, but when can WEP be a good or even better choice?

Answer (score 5):

WEP ***can't be*** a better choice. WPA was developed to offer better security and be able to run on machines which had hardware support for WEP (which is why some devices can't use WPA2). If you can run WEP there is no reason you wouldn|t be able to run WPA from a hardware perspective. The only possible reason is that you don't have any software support anymore.

Answer (score 4):

WEP can be a better choice if you want to teach people how to crack wireless access points, because it is easy to crack. Apart from that use WPA.

Answer (score 3):

Once upon a time, there used to be wlan devices that only supported WEP. So today WEP would be chosen if you want backwards compatibility with those ancient devices that don't support WPA/WPA-2.

Today, WEP offers minimal security and any smart IT person with a few minutes of time and correct hardware can crack it.

WEP should not be used.

Comment: The original Nintendo DS is one of those devices. Was pretty annoying for me.